# Is DynamoDB streams the right option for this use case?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a DynamoDB table that contains key value pairs that will be read by a number of applications. On startup each application will read the entire table and cache it in-memory.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that of getting the applications to update their cache if one or more items in the DynamoDB table have been modified.

DynamoDB streams initially seemed to be the right approach to solving the problem. I have implemented the consumer using Kinesis Client Library (KCL) as recommended by AWS. While implementing it, however, I have encountered some problems that make me believe that I'm on the wrong track. Specifically:

- When I create a new consumer using KCL, it creates a new DynamoDB table to do the housekeeping of leases and checkpoints, such that when the application is restarted, KCL knows which records have been consumed and which have not. This is not what I need for this problem. Any stream records that are created while the application is offline is irrelevant, since the entire table is read upon application startup.
- Several instances of the same application are running at the same time. Each of them needs to be notified of table updates. To implement that in KCL I need to assign a unique application name to each of them. Otherwise they will share the lease table and only one of the applications will get notified. One table for each application instance doesn't seem right. Also I would then need something to remove unused tables.

I also implemented it using the low level API instead. That works fine when there's a single shard. My implementation doesn't handle re-sharding like KCL, however, so it's too fragile. It seems wrong to have to implement handling of re-sharding for the simple problem I'm trying to solve.

I'm beginning to consider other solutions like:

- Implementing a lambda function that gets triggered on updates to the table. The function sends a notification to an SNS topic. Consumers create SQS subscriptions on the topic and gets notified via that. This solution has too many moving parts for my liking.
- Make the applications periodically re-read the entire table and determine themselves if changes have been made. This solution feels a bit primitive, but seems to be the simplest.

All solutions that I have considered so far have quite significant drawbacks. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how your KCL is pushing to the dependent apps but 
I believe the SQS path is the correct choice.

- You can add a presumably infinite number of consumers without being throttled.
- When you do add another dependent app, it won't require changing your KCL to push to it, the new app will simply watch the SQS queue.
- You gain the ability to monitor the queue when issues happen.
- More moving parts to setup, but once you have the `Streams -> SNS -> SQS` pipe in place, it's basically bulletproof.

Just my 2¢.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
You're probably right about it, so I marked your answer as the right one. The many moving parts still bug me, though.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays an AWS [AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) GraphQL API with subscriptions may be the simplest approach to power this type of application, with the least number of moving parts.

Whenever one of your applications starts up, it connects to your AppSync GraphQL API using the [Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/) framework or [AppSync SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js) and subscribes to the updates its interested in. Then whenever an application updates information in the table via your GraphQL API, all your other applications will be notified of the change, along with the relevant changed data.

AppSync integrates well with DynamoDB out of the box, allowing you to generate DynamoDB tables with appropriate indexes alongside your GraphQL or generate GraphQL from your existing DynamoDB tables if you so choose. Amplify can even help you automatically generate an AppSync GraphQL API at a higher level with associated DynamoDB tables, indexes, entity relationships, and more like elasticsearch search capabilities by using their [GraphQL transformers](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql?sdk=js).